# How to declare two actions in ? : format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is as below:

```
if(existingWishlistItem) {
  return wishlistItems.map(wishlistItem => 
    wishlistItem.id === wishlistItemToAdd.id
    ? toast.error('This item is already in your wishlist')
    : wishlistItem
  )
}
```

I want this function to check if there are existing wishlist item in the array, then it pop up an error message to user and return back the wishlistItem array. But I find that I just can write one action after the '?', so are there any ways to pop up the message and return back the wishlistItem at the same time?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do that with `.map()` at all? If you want to show the message, you put the `toast.error()` in the `if` before the `return`. And then you don't actually need to map over the array in order to show a message you know you should show anyway.

Comment: Do you really need to make a **copy** of the `wishlistItems` array? (That's what happens if both branches of your conditional operator evaluate to `wishlistItem`.)

Comment: If you "want this function to check if there are existing wishlist item in the array, then it pop up an error message to user and return back the wishlistItem array" then just literally do that? It's a pretty direct description of the code you want in this case: `if (wishlist.length > 0) { toast.error(...); return wishlist; }`

Comment: Please do not use side effects of a ternary to execute stuff. That is not what they are for

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for pointing it out for me, I think I just ask a silly question... And I need to map over it because I don't want to store the duplicate item for more than one time, so I need to use it to return back the original array

Comment: `.map()` does not do filtering. It returns a 1:1 mapping of the array. If you *already have* a duplicate, you need to use `.filter()`. If you *don't* have a duplicate in the array, then you either return the array directly or, if really needed, you can return a clone of the array with `wishlistItems.slice()` or `Array.from(wishlistItems)` or `[...wishlistItems]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **possible** to do this with the conditional operator, but it's not a good idea. It's hard to read, hard to debug, and easy to get wrong.

Instead, just use an `if`:

```
if (existingWishlistItem) {
    for (const {id} of wishlistItems) {
        if (id === wishlistItemToAdd.id) {
            toast.error('This item is already in your wishlist');
            break; // I assume the ID values are unique, so you can stop here
            // Or: `return wishlistItems;` if you don't need to make a
            // copy in this case
        }
    }
    return wishlistItems; // If you don't need to make a copy
    // Or: `return wishlistItems.slice()` if you do need to make a copy
}
```

(Or — again assuming `id` values are unique — you could use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of the `for-of` loop to find the existing item.)

---

For completeness, you can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to do two things in any expression (including the operands of the conditional operator): `(first, second)`. The comma operator evaluates its left-hand operand, throws away that result, and then evalutes its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result. Applying that to your example:

```
// DON'T DO THIS
if (existingWishlistItem) {
    return wishlistItems.map(wishlistItem => 
        wishlistItem.id === wishlistItemToAdd.id
            ? (toast.error('This item is already in your wishlist'), wishlistItem)
            : wishlistItem
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not what `map` or ternaries are for.

Idiomatically, ternaries are used for conditional behavior that *does not have side effects*. Like `return upperCase ? "HELLO" : "hello"`. This is because complex ternaries are hard to read and so it's hard to tell, at a glance, where the side effect is happening.

Likewise `map` is for transforming objects in a sequence according to some function. It's best practice for `map` to have no side effects, because code is easier to read when side-effects are clearly separated from data transformation.

A far more idiomatic implementation of your code would be:

```js
if(existingWishListItem) {
    if (wishlistItems.some(x => x.id === wishlistItemToAdd.id) {
        toast.error(msg)
    }
    return wishListItems
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which populates a new list of data with the same array length. If you want to find an existing item, you just simply use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). For example

```
if(existingWishlistItem) {
   const foundWishlistItem = wishlistItems.find(wishlistItem => wishlistItem.id === wishlistItemToAdd.id)

   if(foundWishlistItem) {
      toast.error('This item is already in your wishlist')
      //TODO: You can return or do whatever after found existing wishlist item
   }
   return wishlistItems
}
```

Besides that, if you want to have true/false value instead of finding an existing object, you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead

```
if(existingWishlistItem) {
   const isFoundWishlistItem = wishlistItems.some(wishlistItem => wishlistItem.id === wishlistItemToAdd.id)

   if(isFoundWishlistItem) {
      toast.error('This item is already in your wishlist')
      //TODO: You can return or do whatever after found existing wishlist item
   }
   return wishlistItems
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Depends on how you define your action. You can use the `||` operator, and that way first expression is your alert and second is the value you return:

```js
let x = [1,2,3];
let y = x.map((a) => a%2===0? (alert("XXx") || a) : a+1
);
console.log(y);
```